# Is there a way to set my timezone on github.com?

Tags: github, time-zone

Whenever I make a comment/issue or commit. The time is off by 10 hours. I believe it is a timezone issue.

Is there a way to change my timezone for my github account?

Comment: Is you computer up to your current time and date?

Comment: I have this issue; when I hover over "an hour ago", it tells me that I committed something in at 2am- my employer should be so lucky!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such option. However, Github displays most dates in a relative style anyway - and that's based on your system time so those values are correct.

Comment: Not true actually. When I create an issue, I see immediately "crated 10 hours ago".

Comment: Odd, works fine for me (CET)

Comment: You are right. My timezone is off on Linux. Fine on windows.

Comment: fun-fact: sometimes the time on my laptop is ahead of the NTP time by ~1 second; github will then always tell me that I opened an issue or pushed something "in a few seconds". I kinda like that.

Comment: It still shows stuff like "two hours ago" being yesterday when it's almost noon. (Not that the time is off, it's correct, it's just dates that get a bit annoying.)

Comment: @njsg same here...

Answer (score 5):

Since March, 2014 you can, by using Github's commit API to specify the exact timestamp for your commit.

To see the the format [refer to the developer's documentation](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-03-04-timezone-handling-changes/).

Or you can set the timezone by passing it in headers while making the post request in a commit. like
`curl -H "Time-Zone: Europe/Amsterdam" -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/contents/new_file.md`

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I changed my computers system date/time (I use Lubuntu Linux by the way).

Here's the steps I followed:

- 1st - At 1am 9/30/19 I logged out of GitHub.
- 2nd - I changed my computers date/time to Los Angeles time. So since
  I am in Florida my date and time changed to 11pm 9/29/19.
- 3rd I logged back into GitHub

Result:
Instead of GitHub showing 9/30/19 in the heatmap, it showed 9/29/19.

Have fun!